# Why can I not parse the JSON from YouTube Data API in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, youtube-data-api

I am trying to parse a response from the YouTube Data API 3 into my node.js project. When I call JSON.parse(), it stops part way through the JSON and throws an "Unexpected end of JSON input" error.

I cam new to node.js and the YouTube Data API, but I was unable to find any issues with the JSON that was returned that could cause this error.

My request code:

```
   https.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + gameSearch + '+trailer&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&key=Google_API_Key', (res) => {


res.on('data', (d) => {

    var result = JSON.parse(d.toString('utf8');

    console.log(result);
```

response data (Example only for context):

```
        {
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/c5qJp8_01Z7pygk7E4FxXPySdrE\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 834115,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Kd8M7QMYXGvUuq22Gmm8tSsH2Og\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "QpvM9uwOcUc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-06-09T13:13:41.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC64oAui-2WN5vXC7hTKoLbg",
    "title": "Elder Scrolls 5 : Skyrim Official Trailer",
    "description": "Elder Scrolls 5 Skyrim - E3 2011 Trailer. Join us on Facebook : http://facebook.com/GameNewsOfficial. Subscribe Now  ! Bethesda ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QpvM9uwOcUc/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QpvM9uwOcUc/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QpvM9uwOcUc/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "GameNewsOfficial",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/9ufokW0y_tAzTii-9cOHe9z-V9M\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "JSRtYpNRoN0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-02-23T20:12:28.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvZHe-SP3xC7DdOk4Ri8QBw",
    "title": "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim - Official Trailer",
    "description": "We're pleased to share the first ever in-game trailer for The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, the next installment in The Elder Scrolls series from award-winning creators ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSRtYpNRoN0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSRtYpNRoN0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSRtYpNRoN0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Bethesda Softworks",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/JmkNelVuuT7Bu7O7dcOyMIu-rIw\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "yoXFk-0NrDI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2010-12-13T21:36:13.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvZHe-SP3xC7DdOk4Ri8QBw",
    "title": "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Announcement Trailer",
    "description": "Watch the announcement trailer for The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim... coming to Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, and PC on 11.11.11 ESRB RATING: MATURE with Blood ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yoXFk-0NrDI/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yoXFk-0NrDI/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yoXFk-0NrDI/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Bethesda Softworks",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/BNQ1UBBPS3Zb9cjx8Mu1yDEFlo0\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "iX1JmaYdWa0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-04-26T02:29:59.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCY7SikBhJcjMbMaN_L7l3WQ",
    "title": "Skyrim - Wyrmstooth trailer",
    "description": "SKYRIM WYRMSTOOTH : http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25704/? ENB : Vividian - http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/36067/? MUSIC : 00:00 ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iX1JmaYdWa0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iX1JmaYdWa0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iX1JmaYdWa0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Tyroine",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/C80AcqmGPGxNkgpTifXvbWmFFBs\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "aLt0rSKClLA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-03-04T20:50:59.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCU25Nxe7qWJKtNaTqU9GdSQ",
    "title": "TES:V Skyrim Official Trailer HD (české titulky)",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aLt0rSKClLA/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aLt0rSKClLA/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aLt0rSKClLA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Kamil Doskočil",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Error that I keep receiving:

```
 undefined:46   
    "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/9ufokW0y_tAzTii-9cOHe9z-V9M\"


    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
        at Object.parse (native)
        at IncomingMessage.https.get.res.on (/home/ubuntu/workspace/oldFile.js:289:23)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
        at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:129:22)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:361:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

I can see it seems to be parsing up until the second element in the "items" array and I cannot figure out why it's breaking!!

Cheers

Comment: Your json in invalid.

Comment: maybe  you need to set the proper encoding correctly 
try this  before  res.on('data',d=>
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

Comment: JSON was not complete as I wanted to keep it short. I have posted the full JSON data.

Comment: Hi Fadi, Appreciate your response. I tried your recommendation and the error remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold onto all the chunks of data you're receiving until the response has ended:

```
https.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + gameSearch + '+trailer&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&key=Google_API_Key', (res) => {
  const chunks = []
  res.on('data', (d) => { chunks.push(d) })
  res.on('end', () => {
    var result = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString())
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm getting another error now. The error I am getting now is : SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier referring to the var result declaration.

I tried changing the layout and checked for missing bracket and parenthesis but I am not able to find the issue.......

Comment: @Djinné22 my bad, I was missing `() =>` before the on end listener. Should be good now.

Comment: You're a legend!! thanks heaps for that! worked a treat.